# tensorflow: it is possible to build a neural network with categorical targets with one hot encoding?

Tags: python, tensorflow, target, one-hot-encoding

I have a dataset in which the targets are categories of products purchased by a customer. 
Each customer can buy one or more categories.

like this:

[image]

Previously, I built this model to work with a single target (buy or not buy for each client):

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
                            tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation='tanh'), 
                            tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation='tanh'), 
                            tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_size, activation='softmax') 
                            ])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

batch_size = 20000
max_epochs = 200
early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=2) 
model.fit(train_inputs,
          train_targets,
          batch_size = batch_size,
          epochs = max_epochs,
          callbacks = [early_stopping],
          validation_data = (validation_inputs, validation_targets),
          verbose=2)
```

it is necessary to generate a dataset with the one hot encoding before creating the targets, and then use them as a [n x 5] tensor?. With the one hot encoding, the client 1, for example, has the target:
[0,0,1,0,1]:

[image]

How can I build the model to work with targets like this?

or the targets can be encoded with tensorflow inside the model?

Sorry if my question is a little basic, but I'm just starting to work with tensorflow

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for multi-label classification.

In such a scenario, your output will be still one-hot-encoded but there will be multiple targets. For example, `[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]`.

Your network structure will be same, except your final activation has to be `sigmoid` instead of `softmax` and you will train your model with `binary_crossentropy` loss.

ref: https://www.kaggle.com/roccoli/multi-label-classification-with-keras

Answer (score 1):

This is the case of multi-class, multi-label classification. Unlike `softmax` where the output are mutually inclusive(If one output is true then other will be false), you are handling cases where output is mutually exclusive. It should focus upon whether the client bought `jacket` or not, whether the client bought `t shirt` or not than focusing on the fact that if I bought `jacket` then I will not buy `t shirt`. In this case, the output solely focuses on its corresponding output. To achieve this, we use `sigmoid` where each output value of your `hot vector encoded` output learns on itself. 
In order to learn that, your loss will be `binary cross entropy` where the output `jacket`,`t shirt` and so on is learnt whether it was bought or not, independent of each other.

Comment: thanks, this is very clear. But in my case, should the train input be a [5x4] tensor or a [3x4] tensor? that is, must each row be a customer and a purchase or just a customer?. Likewise, should the train output be a 5x1 array or a 3x5 tensor?

Comment: I propose that your training input should still be [5x4] since age,location and other input values might decide what you are going to buy. You can still keep your output one hot encoded as suggested which will be length of 5 for each row. I don't know what data looks likes so I suggest using this and look how your network behaves.